# Deleting old indices on ElasticSearch Kibana?

Tags: kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I did my research and I am aware you can use ILM on proper Kibana for that. However, ES Kibana doesn't have that option, and I'm not sure how to write a policy for it. Google and GPT didn't help. Any docs I can look at? Thank you?

Comment: what do you mean by ES Kibana? and how it differs from what you refer to as "proper Kibana"? also, what version you're using?

Comment: Amazon OpenSearch Service, Elasticsearch 7.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I appreciate you’re using Amazon Opensearch Service and you’re looking for ILM. In OpenSearch this feature is called Index State Management (ISM) and you can find more info on how to write policies here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/ism.html